# 'locationManager(_:didRangeBeacons:inRegion:)' conflicts with optional requirement method 'locationManager(_:didRangeBeacons:inRegion:)' in protocol

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cllocationmanager, ibeacon

This is the full error message:

```
Objective-C method 'locationManager:didRangeBeacons:inRegion:' provided by method 'locationManager(_:didRangeBeacons:inRegion:)' conflicts with optional requirement method 'locationManager(_:didRangeBeacons:inRegion:)' in protocol 'CLLocationManagerDelegate'
```

This is my app delegate

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
    var locationManager: CLLocationManager?

    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        let uuidString = "EBEFD083-70A2-47C8-9837-E7B5634DF524"
        let beaconIdentifier = "iBeaconModules.us"
        let beaconUUID:NSUUID = NSUUID(UUIDString: uuidString)!
        let beaconRegion:CLBeaconRegion = CLBeaconRegion(proximityUUID: beaconUUID,
            identifier: beaconIdentifier)

        locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        if(locationManager!.respondsToSelector("requestAlwaysAuthorization")) {
            locationManager!.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        }
        locationManager!.delegate = self
        locationManager!.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = false

        locationManager!.startMonitoringForRegion(beaconRegion)
        locationManager!.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(beaconRegion)
        locationManager!.startUpdatingLocation()
        return true
    }

    func applicationWillResignActive(application: UIApplication) {
        // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
        // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
    }

    func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {
        // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
        // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
    }

    func applicationWillEnterForeground(application: UIApplication) {
        // Called as part of the transition from the background to the inactive state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
    }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {
        // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(application: UIApplication) {
        // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
    }


}

extension AppDelegate: CLLocationManagerDelegate {
        func sendLocalNotificationWithMessage(message: String!) {
            let notification:UILocalNotification = UILocalNotification()
            notification.alertBody = message
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notification)
        }

        func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!,
            didRangeBeacons beacons: [AnyObject]!,
            inRegion region: CLBeaconRegion!) {
                NSLog("didRangeBeacons");
                var message:String = ""

                if(beacons.count > 0) {
                    let nearestBeacon:CLBeacon = beacons[0] as! CLBeacon


                    switch nearestBeacon.proximity {
                    case CLProximity.Far:
                        message = "You are far away from the beacon"
                    case CLProximity.Near:
                        message = "You are near the beacon"
                    case CLProximity.Immediate:
                        message = "You are in the immediate proximity of the beacon"
                    case CLProximity.Unknown:
                        return
                    }
                } else {
                    message = "No beacons are nearby"
                }

                NSLog("%@", message)
                sendLocalNotificationWithMessage(message)
        }
}
```

The error appears on the line beginning `func locationManager`

I take this to mean that the CLLocationManager delegate already has a method named didRangeBeacons:inRegion that I am not allowed to override in my extension. But I am new to swift and most of the solutions to this type of error include changes to swift declarations in different versions of Swift. Any advice on how to get rid of this? And explanation for why it is happening?

Comment: This code compiles for me just fine on XCode 6.4

Comment: i am on Xcode 7 beta 6. perhaps thats why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know enough about swift to say why this fixed it (perhaps someone can elaborate, but using this instead of whats in the code above fixed it:

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager,
            didRangeBeacons beacons: [CLBeacon],
            inRegion region: CLBeaconRegion)
```

and when I say fixed it, I mean that it compiles now. I haven't successfully tried it with a  real beacon.

also, I copied this code directly from this doc page:

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManagerDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/CLLocationManagerDelegate/locationManager:didRangeBeacons:inRegion: